# How to write data from mongo stream to *.txt file

Tags: mongodb, stream

I using mongodb driver on NodeJS to query data, but the result data is too much and response time is slow. So I tried to stream data from mongo to a file and send this file to the front end.

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
const { Transform } = require('stream');
const fs = require('fs');

const run = async () => {
  const url = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
  const client = new MongoClient(url);
  const dbName = 'dbName';
  await client.connect();
  const db = client.db(dbName);
  const collection = db.collection('test');
  const stream = await collection.find({ name: '123123123' })
    .sort({ age: -1 })
    .limit(20000)
    .stream();

  stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('text.txt'));
  return collection;
};

run();
```

but when I run this code, it's throw a error:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "chunk" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array. Received an instance of Object
```

How I can fix this ?